# Is there any library or tool to "translate" string from one keyboard layout to another?

Tags: bash, keyboard-layout, tr

I want to write simple bash script which translates input between different keyboard layout. For example, if my system has Russian and English layouts, and I'm passing 'Руддщ' string to this script, it should output 'Hello'.

Currently I'm using this code:

```
echo "$@" | iconv -t cp1251 | tr $(echo "[йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэ\\ячсмитьбю.ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭ/ЯЧСМИТЬБЮ,\"№;:?Ёё]" | iconv -t cp1251) "[qwertyuiop\[\]asdfghjkl;'\\zxcvbnm,./QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\"|ZXCVBNM<>?@#$^&~\`]"
```

There are obvious disadvantages:

- I have to use `iconv`, because my system uses utf8 and `tr` can't use it.
- I have to type all characters manually, which leads to lack of applicability and high error possibility.

I know `xneur` has simillar functionality, but I don't want to switch layout on the fly, just translate strings on request. I've looked through `xneur` source code, but haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

I guess *some* library for this exists (if only internally at Google?). For example, https://www.google.com/search?q=hjccbz correctly displays results for россия. It doesn't work for [ghbdtn](https://www.google.com/search?q=ghbdtn), though (perhaps because misspelling привет like this is a common in-joke?)

In fact, searching for these strings brings up some half-promising hits, though nothing clearly directly applicable.

Anyway, there is no reason you couldn't put your own code in a script, which obviously removes the need for retyping this correctly.

If you save this with a CP1251 encoding from your editor, you can avoid the nested `iconv`:

```
#!/bin/sh
LC_ALL=C
iconv -t cp1251 |
tr 'йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэ\ячсмитьбю.ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭ/ЯЧСМИТЬБЮ,"№;:?Ёё' "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'\\zxcvbnm,./QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\"|ZXCVBNM<>?@#$^&~\`"
```

I *think* you had a false assumption about needing to use square brackets around the arguments to `tr` which I also attempted to fix.

Save to a location in your `PATH` with a memorable and easy to type name, `chmod +x`, and there you have it.

Comment: The Google transliteration examples are obviously in the opposite direction. I don't have a Cyrillic keyboard so it's hard to test if they do this both ways (getting this far was already a challenge with only my phone to test on) but I'd guess they do.

Comment: [`tr` from the latest release of GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tr-invocation.html#tr-invocation) does not support UTF-8. You can *run* it in a UTF-8 locale, and you can pass it arguments outside the ASCII range, but it'll still operate on bytes, not characters, so it won't translate non-ASCII characters correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your improvement to my code, it's definetely better this way. But I still beleive there is some better solution which I'm missing, so not closing the question yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t imagine this is possible since, with a give layout, there can be several ways to type the same character. For example, with my french layout, I can type “É” either either by enabling `CapsLock` and typing `é`, or by `Compose`-`'`-`Shift`-`e`.

Comment: Why is that a problem? Just define two mappings to the same output. You can't get 100% reliable round-trip translation back to the original input but that should not matter at all for this particular use case.

Comment: @tripleee It is a problem because the different ways to type one character with keyboard layout 1 might result in different characters in keyboard layout 2. The basic US layout has no redundancy, but many others do. For example, with a French keyboard, é is what is 2 on a Russian keyboard, whereas Compose+'+e is Compose+э+у — granted that one doesn't do anything, but there might be others that do.

Comment: Of course, if there are multiple ways to type `a` on a keyboard, and they correspond to different characters in the destination mapping, you can't know which one to choose. But can you give a practical example for the scenario at hand? The fact that the OP has a basically working solution should already convince you that the problem is practically solvable for the case of Russian cyrillics to US English alphabetics.

Comment: And even if there are some ambiguities, many can be resolved by context. If `a` could be typed two ways, you can still in practice guess whether "alphabet" or "blphbbet" is correct with a bit of character trigram statistics or (in the worst case) brute force a lot of the time.

Comment: @tripleee It might work for “textual” inputs, although using trigram statistics is significantly more complicated than a transliteration. But it might not work for more “random-like” inputs, such as password inputs. So I guess all depends what the OP intends to do…